# Unable to connect via TCP connection to Android

Tags: c#, tcp, server, xamarin.android, connection

I`m currently in progress of making an Android app which needs to connect through TCP/IP to a Windows PC, where Windows PC is the ***Server*** and Android is a ***Client***. The problem is somewhere into the Connection! Whenever I try to start the connection it keeps *Waiting* for Client and when the connect button is clicked in client nothing really happens!

The Server side code which I`m working is,

```
TcpListener listner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8126);
    NetworkStream netstream;
    TcpClient client;
    byte[] datalength = new byte[4];

    public void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread startconnection = new Thread(new ThreadStart(connect));
        startconnection.Start();

    }

    public void connect()
    {


        try
        {
            listner.Start(); //Starts Listening to any IP with port 8126

            //Invoked Just because of CrossThreading Error

            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                this.lbl_status.Text = "Status : Waiting for Client";
            }));

            //Invoke Complete.



            listner.Server.Listen(1);
            client = listner.AcceptTcpClient();


            if (client.Connected)
            {
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    this.lbl_status.Text = "Status : Connected Successfully";
                }));
                //serverReceive();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //lbl_status.Text = "Status : " + ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And the Client side code as,

```
        TcpClient tcpclient;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button btnConnectClick = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConnect);
        btnConnectClick.Click += BtnConnectClick_Click;


    }

    private void BtnConnectClick_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Connection waiting", ToastLength.Long);
        try
        {
           IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(Resource.Id.ipadd.ToString()); //Ip from textbox

            tcpclient.Connect(ip, 8126);
            if (tcpclient.Connected)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Connected Successfully!", ToastLength.Long);
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long);

        }

    }
```

I don`t know where the exact problem is!

Comment: Are u using a packet sniffer like WireShark to verify that packets are sent?

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code with WPF application as server on PC site and Xamarin.Android app as client on real device.

Works fine by my side. The only problem I found with your code is that in your client side, you didn't initialize the `tcpclient`, the `tcpclient` is null when you code `tcpclient.Connect(ip, 8126);` (but it doesn't throw an exception), I simply modified your code like this:

```cs
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("..."); //Ip from textbox
tcpclient = new TcpClient();
tcpclient.ConnectAsync(ip, 8126);
```

You can have a try, if still doesn't work, make sure your devices are in the same  network.

Comment: I`ve tried this solution, but it is not working!!! Can you please send the solution you tried on? Also my devices are on same network!

Comment: @KuldeepThakre, the code is same as yours. Check my [demo](https://github.com/GraceFeng/TCPBetweenWPFAndAndroid).

Comment: Thankyou! This code works totally fine, I`ll check my code soon and update here what was wrong! Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Do you know what is `Resource.Id.ipadd.ToString()` returning? It's a number like 2130968576. Your OnCreate method must be

```
EditText ipadd;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    Button btnConnectClick = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConnect);.
    ipadd = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.ipadd); // Create object of textbox
    btnConnectClick.Click += BtnConnectClick_Click;


}
```

then use

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipadd.Text);
```

it will return IP address.

Comment: What is wrong with `var ip = IPAddress.Parse(3232235786.ToString());`? it is equal to `192.168.1.10`

Comment: No, it isn't equal to `192.168.1.10`. 3232235786 is pointing to your EditText and its constant (see Resource.Id in Resource.Designer.cs, there is a `public const int ipadd = 3232235786`).

Comment: `No, it isn't equal to 192.168.1.10`. Have you tried to run above 1 line code? see what you get in *ip*

Comment: Well, now I tried it, it worked, sorry. But where did you get number 3232235786? Is it `Resource.Id.ipadd`?

Comment: It is just an example to show your assumptions may not be correct. Here is the google's dns server `134744072` or stackoverflow.com `2539979077`

Comment: How do you convert IP address to number?

Comment: all in all, an [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address is a 32 bit number. I leave it to you as an exercise :) .

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer here, the code that I was executing was correct and the TCP Connection was being established successfully all the time, but problem was with this,

`if (client.Connected)
            {
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    this.lbl_status.Text = "Status : Connected Successfully";
                }));
            }`

Every time it was connecting the `Client.Connected` returned `False` I`m not sure why.
Is there any other way to check if the client is connected or not?